# Polling with RxJS that can recover missed events

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to use RxJS to poll for events. However, I only have access to one function, which is `getEvent()`. I can do 2 things with the `getEvent` function:

1. `getEvent("latest")` — this will give me the latest event object
2. `getEvent(eventId)` - I pass in an integer and it will give me the event object corresponding to the `eventId`.

Event IDs always increment from 0, but the problem is, if my polling interval isn't small enough, I might miss events.

For example, if I do a `getEvent("latest")` and I get an event that has an ID of 1, that's great. But if the next time I call it, I get an ID of 3, I know that I missed an event.

In this case, I want to use a higher-order observable to call `getEvent(2)` and `getEvent(3)` so that the consumer of the stream I am creating won't have to worry about missing an event.

Right now, all I have is something like this:

```
timer(0, 500).pipe(
  concatMap(() => from(getEvent("latest"))
)
```

For some context, I'm working off of this blogpost: https://itnext.io/polling-using-rxjs-b56cd3531815

Answer (score 2):

Using `expand` to recursively call GET fits here perfectly. Here is [an example with DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yopsau?file=index.ts):

```
const source = timer(0, 2000)

const _stream = new Subject();
const stream = _stream.asObservable();

const s1 = source.pipe(tap(random)).subscribe()    

const sub = stream.pipe(
  startWith(0),
  pairwise(),  
  concatMap((v: Array<number>) => {
    let missing = v[1] - v[0];
    return missing ? getMissing(v[0], missing) : EMPTY
  })
).subscribe(console.log)

function getMissing(start, count) {
  return getById(start).pipe(
    expand(id => getById(id+1)),
    take(count)
  )  
}

// helper functions for DEMO

let i = 1;
function random() {. // THIS IS YOUR getEvent('latest')
  if (i < 10) {
    i+=2;
    _stream.next(i
      // (Math.floor(Math.random() * 8))
    )
  }
}

function getById(id) {.  // THIS IS YOUR getEvent(eventId)
  return of(id).pipe(delay(1000)) // delay to mimic network
}
```